# std_msgs::ColorRGBA is not coloring specific markers on RViz

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, visualization-msgs, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish colored `LINE_STRIPS` markers on `RViz`.
I came across [this message](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/ColorRGBA.html) and tried to apply it to my case. Although all markers are published, **the problem I have** is that specific segments are not being published with the specific color I am trying to show.

The error I get from `RViz` is: `Number of colors doesn't match number of points.`

```
#include "segmentpublisher.h"
#include "constants.h"
#include <ColorRGBA.h>

SegmentPublisher::SegmentPublisher() {}

void SegmentPublisher::initPublisher(ros::NodeHandle nh, std::string name) {
    markerPublisher = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>(name,10);
    m_initialized = true;
}

void SegmentPublisher::publish(PointData inPointData) {
    if(m_initialized) {
        markerPublisher.publish(fromPointDataToSegment(inPointData, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    }
}

void SegmentPublisher::publish(PointData inPointData, float r, float g, float b) {
    if(m_initialized) {
        markerPublisher.publish(fromPointDataToSegment(inPointData, r, g, b));
    }
}


visualization_msgs::Marker SegmentPublisher::fromPointDataToSegment(PointData inPointData, float r, float g, float b)
{
    visualization_msgs::Marker segment;
    segment.header.frame_id = "/segment_frame";
    segment.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    segment.ns = "distance";
    segment.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
    segment.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
    segment.id = 0;
    segment.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_LIST;
    segment.scale.x = 0.03f;
    segment.color.r = r;
    segment.color.g = g;
    segment.color.b = b;
    segment.color.a = 0.5f;

    geometry_msgs::Point segment_a, segment_b, segment_c, segment_d;
    /* segment_a is the lidar origin */
    segment_a.x = 0.0f;
    segment_a.y = 0.0f;
    segment_a.z = 0.25f;

// other operations ...
}

    if(inPointData.dockDistance() < Constants::maxDistanceDetected)
    {

        std_msgs::ColorRGBA color;
        color.r = 255;
        color.g = 0;
        color.b = 0;
        color.a = 1;

        segment_b.x = inPointData.point().x;
        segment_b.y = inPointData.point().y;
        segment_b.z = segment_a.z + inPointData.point().z;

        segment_d.x = 0.0f;
        segment_d.y = inPointData.point().y;
        segment_d.z = 0.0f;

        /* Publish segment point to y-axis */
        segment.points.push_back(segment_b); // <--  trying to color this segment
        segment.points.push_back(segment_d); //  <--  trying to color this segment
    }
    else
    {
        segment_b = segment_a;
        segment_b.z += 1.0f;

        segment.points.push_back(segment_a);
        segment.points.push_back(segment_b);
    }

    return segment;
}
```

I came across [this source](https://answers.ros.org/question/9297/std_msgscolorrgbadisplaying-different-color-for-each-point/) and [this source too](https://answers.ros.org/question/53527/a-std_msgscolorrgba-message/) but could not understand what I am missing to show the color I am looking for. I also consulted [this](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/std_msgs/html/ColorRGBA_8h_source.html) source to see if I was missing something useful.

Please point to the right direction for solving this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352880/std_msgs::colorrgba-is-not-coloring-specific-markers-on-rviz/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2020-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is defined here: [Raw Message Definition](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html), more precisely in these lines:

```
#Only used if the type specified has some use for them (eg. POINTS, LINE_STRIP, ...)
geometry_msgs/Point[] points
#Only used if the type specified has some use for them (eg. POINTS, LINE_STRIP, ...)
#number of colors must either be 0 or equal to the number of points
#NOTE: alpha is not yet used
std_msgs/ColorRGBA[] colors
```

You are pushing back into **points** but you are missing to push back  into **colors** (also member of the visualization_msgs/Marker message), defined in this line:

```
 std_msgs/ColorRGBA[] colors
```

This part you already have:

```
   segment.points.push_back(segment_a);
   segment.points.push_back(segment_b);
```

This part you are still missing:

```
  // push back one color per segment
  segment.colors.push_back(segment_a.color); // pass in any std_msgs::ColorRGBA object
  segment.colors.push_back(segment_b.color);
```

The number of colors you push back has to match the number of points (you are calling them segments) that you push back.

---

Originally posted by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) with karma: 500 on 2020-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1